# Marketing Cloud Upgrade from Enterprise 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am looking for documentation or any reference on how to Upgrade Marketing cloud Enterprise 1.0 account to 2.0. Can some one please share the links or documents on how to Upgrade the existing Enterprise account to 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to get in touch with your account rep for assistance with this. As far as I'm aware to move to 2.0 you'll need an entirely new account instance provisioned.

Answer (score 2):

Having completed many of these "upgrades" in my time, you won't find any specific documentation.

Your E1 and E2 accounts will be entirely separate - two different environments. You will need to treat the "upgrade" as a completely new implementation. There are some elements you can copy/paste across e.g. templates but you will need to configure everything from scratch. Start with Business Units, SAPs/IP, Users, Data Schemas, Imports etc.

Best of luck with it. Check Marketing Cloud documentation for configuration guides on each - but treat the whole experience as a pretty big project. No simple installer or double-click upgrade path unfortunately